# How can I change Table Name in Room Database dynamically in android

Tags: java, android, database, android-room

I am trying to create a chatting app for demo purpose but I came across a problem where I want to save chat history in the database, I am trying to do that with Room Database, I want to save chat history in the different - different table for clarity using chatID (for different - different user).

Comment: Room is just an ORM so anything that is possible with sqlite is also possible with Room. You just need to map out your schema and how you want to store your data.

Comment: "I want to save chat history in the different - different table for clarity using chatID" -- that is not possible with Room.

Comment: @CommonsWare So How can I save my chat history in the database?

Comment: Use one table, with chatID as a column in that table.